# HtmlAgilityPack and windows 8 winRT

Tags: windows-runtime, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to build a metro app for windows 8. In this app i'm trying to parse data from a website. For that i'm using HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.6. BUT i'm getting really confused about 'Dose HAP 1.4.6 works with windows 8?' and 'Dose it support Xpath?' Too much confusing info on Codeplex. As for now it seems that it works on windows 8 BUT i can't see HtmlNode.SelectNode method. If Xpath is not working, is there any other option to do the parsing? Can you direct me to a tutorial or examples? please...

Yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LINQ API:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(contents);
var programmes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(d => d.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "program")
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find much up-to-date information on this API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bart! I just converted my data to xml and parsing it using SgmlReader. I might give LINQ API a test soon (Just out of curiosity)

Answer (score 0):

I was created few weeks ago my own algorithm to save web page and I also solved problem for parsing html code for **img css js** in windows 8 metro-app with help of these few lines:(for all images, in `HtmlDocument html`, links example)

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> imghrefNodes = html.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "img");
foreach (HtmlNode img in imghrefNodes)
{
   HtmlAttribute att = img.Attributes["src"];
   //in att.Value you can find your img url
   //Here you can do everything what you want with all img links by editing att.Value
}
```

For css you can just replace `img` with `link` and  `src` with `href`. For other nodes the same way.