# HTML Parser for Windows 10 (UWP)

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

Is there any HTML parser using `X-Path` for `UWP` - Windows 10?

What's the easy/best way of exploring HTML in Windows 10 ?

Comment: [htmlagilitypack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com)

Comment: @Graffito Didn't support ... Got error in SelectNode method ... Like Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Did you declare the Html doc as "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument" and not simply as "HtmlDocument" ?

Comment: Yes,I tried this code    `(new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()).DocumentNode.SelectNodes`     But There is not SelectNodes method

Comment: [Official answer from the author](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15941723/124386) - you can't use XPath; you have to use LINQ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack

https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/

Solution 2: Parsing Html

```
private async void Parsing(string website)
       {
           try
           {
               HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
               var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(website);
               String source = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
               source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);
               HtmlDocument resultat = new HtmlDocument();
               resultat.LoadHtml(source);


           List&lt;HtmlNode&gt; toftitle = resultat.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where
           (x =&gt; (x.Name == "div" &amp;&amp; x.Attributes["class"] != null &amp;&amp; x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("block_content"))).ToList();

           var li = toftitle[6].Descendants("li").ToList();
           foreach (var item in li)
           {
               var link = item.Descendants("a").ToList()[0].GetAttributeValue("href", null);
               var img = item.Descendants("img").ToList()[0].GetAttributeValue("src", null);
               var title = item.Descendants("h5").ToList()[0].InnerText;

               listproduct.Add(new Product()
               {
                   Img = img,
                   Title = title,
                   Link = link
               });
           }

       }
       catch (Exception)
       {

           MessageBox.Show("Network Problem!");
       }

   }
```

[Windows 8 Parsing Html using C# sample in C# for Visual Studio 2013[^]](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Parsing-Html-using-C-721be358#content)