# HtmlAgility:no contents appeared (C#,UWP)

Tags: c#, html, win-universal-app, uwp, html-agility-pack

i tried to use htmlagilitypack to parse a table,after i ve done i realized that i forgot to prove if htmlagility part works or not.
...
and its obvious it doesnt work
i also didnt know what have i missed and where have i done totally wrong...
cause i m a beginner...
so pls dont be too hard on me.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Net.Http.HttpClient
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        string header = "ie";
        if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
        }

        header = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
        if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
        }

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();


        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(" http://www.eurogymnasium-waldenburg.de/egw_content/Stunden_Vertretungsplan/home.html");



        HtmlNode docNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode;

        HtmlNode navNode = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("bereichaktionen");

        HtmlNode docNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body[@class='ui-widget']/div[@id='main']/div[@id='vplan']/div[@id='bereichaktionen']");

        string nodeValue;

        nodeValue = (docNode.InnerText);

        Debug.WriteLine("nodeValue");
```

// i doubt theres somethin wrong above but im not sure whats wrong.

```
        if (htmlDoc.ParseErrors != null && htmlDoc.ParseErrors.Count() > 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {

            if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
            {
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

                if (bodyNode != null)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the origin url is there ,u guys could have a try

Thank y'all
X.L

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941529/htmlagilitypack-windows-8-metro-apps/15941723#15941723

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the third party package [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) you are using currently is not supported in universal app. Please use [HtmlAgilityPack for .NET Core 1.4.9.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore/)  which is supported in universal app.

Secondly, the parameter of the method `htmlDoc.LoadHtml(string html)`  is not the Uri of html site, but the html content which can be got from a webrequest's response.

So the right code should be as followings:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.eurogymnasium-waldenburg.de/egw_content/Stunden_Vertretungsplan/home.html");
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var result = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(result);
var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body[@class='ui-widget']/div[@id='main']/div[@id='vplan']/div[@id='bereichaktionen']");
```

And I also upload the complete project [CHtmlAgility](https://github.com/sunteenwu/PersonalDemo/tree/master/CHtmlAgility) to github you can download for testing.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack for UWP (also WinRT and other similar tech) doesn't support XPath. Answer from the man behind HtmlAgilityPack himself https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941723/5562523

> The Html Agility Pack relies on .NET for the XPATH implementation. Unfortunately, WinRT doesn't support XPATH, so you don't have anything related to XPATH in Html Agility Pack for WinRT.