# Windows 10 universal app WebView without page

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

Is there way to use WebView without actual page?

I tried to instantiate webview via new WebView() and then call Navigate to url but navigation completed handler that I register for is not called.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to instantiate webview via new WebView() and then call Navigate to url but navigation completed handler that I register for is not called.

We need to add the `WebView` control into to a xaml container(`Grid`, `StackPanel` etc), then the [WebView.NavigationCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationcompleted.aspx) event will be called when the `WebView` has finished loading the current content or if navigation has failed.

For example:

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="rootGrid">

</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        WebView wb = new WebView();
        wb.Source = new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com");
        wb.NavigationCompleted += Wb_NavigationCompleted;
        rootGrid.Children.Add(wb);
    }

    private void Wb_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

**If you don't want to show WebView page in your UI, just set `Visibility` property to `Collapsed`**

```
wb.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

**------Update 07/28/2016-------**

If you just need to load html page from code behind, the `WebView` control is not the right choice, there are two solutions:

1. Using [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) class to request webpage

   Check [the official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient)
2. Using third-party library, for example, **Html Agility Pack**, please see Sunteen's answer in this question: [HtmlAgility:no contents appeared (C#,UWP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896836/htmlagilityno-contents-appeared-c-uwp)

Comment: I do not have the page.

Comment: @user1744147 If you just need to load html page from code behind, please see my updated part in answer