# Getting the title of a HTML element with Xpath UWP C#

Tags: c#, html, xpath, uwp, html-agility-pack

With this code I get the HTLM document:

```
private static async Task<HtmlDocument> GetHtmlOfPage(string website)
{
           return await new HtmlWeb().LoadFromWebAsync(website);
}
```

The Xpath of the element is:

```
id('ContentHolderMain_ContentHolderMainContent_ContentHolderMainContent_pnlDaily')/x:div/x:ol/x:li[3]/x:ul
```

(using Xpath Checker for firefox).

The code for retrieving the values:

```
public List<string> GetTypesOfFood(string website)
{
        List<string> TypesOfFood = new List<string>();

        HtmlDocument document = GetHtmlOfPage(website).Result;
        /* HtmlNode docNodes = document.DocumentNode;
         HtmlNode ul = docNodes.Element("id('ContentHolderMain_ContentHolderMainContent_ContentHolderMainContent_pnlDaily')/x:div/x:ol/x:li[1]/x:ul[@title]");*/

        HtmlNode div = document.GetElementbyId("ContentHolderMain_ContentHolderMainContent_ContentHolderMainContent_pnlDaily");

        if(div != null)
        {
            var ul = div.Element("//div[@class='holderRestaurantInfo']/ol/li[1]/ul/@title").GetAttributeValue("title", "title");
            string a = ul;

            TypesOfFood.Add(a);
        }

        return TypesOfFood;
}
```

I expect values like "Meat", "Vegatarian",.... but I get no results. What I am doing wrong and how to use Xpath with UWP?

**Update (21.6.2017):**

I finally managed to get the values I was looking for:

```
public List<string> GetTypesOfFood()
    {
        if(!InternetConnection)
        {
            flag = -3;
            return null;
        }
        List<string> TypesOfFood = new List<string>();

        WebResponse response = GetResponse().Result;
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string result = "";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }


        HtmlDocument MobileDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        MobileDocument.LoadHtml(result);

           var images = MobileDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@class='pull-right']"); 
            foreach(var image in images)
            {
                HtmlAttribute title = image.Attributes[@"title"];
                TypesOfFood.Add(title.Value);
            }
     return TypesOfFood;
    }
   private async Task<WebResponse> GetResponse()
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://www.studentska-prehrana.si/sl/restaurant/Details/2521");
        WebResponse r = await req.GetResponseAsync();
            return r;
    }
```

Edit: It also seems my Firefox Xpath plugin is outdated due to the "x:" signs. No code uses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am doing wrong and how to use Xpath with UWP?

According to your code snippet, it seems like the third party package you are trying to use is [`Html Agility Pack`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) which is not fully supported in universal app currently. Please try to use [`HtmlAgilityPack for .NET Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore/) which is supported in UWP app.

Using [Xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) in UWP can be same as what you did in other places. For example, using `SelectNodes` method of `HtmlAgilityPack for .NET Core` with Xpath  string above as follows:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("your uri");
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var result = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
HtmlDocument MobileDocument = new HtmlDocument();
MobileDocument.LoadHtml(result);
var nodes = MobileDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//id('ContentHolderMain_ContentHolderMainContent_ContentHolderMainContent_pnlDaily')/x:div/x:ol/x:li[3]/x:ul]");
foreach (var item in nodes)
{ 
 ...
}
```

There is a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896836/htmlagilityno-contents-appeared-c-uwp) you may also reference. If you still have issues, provide the html content or the html Url to let us have testing on our side.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. My code was working one day and then the whole site got renewed, there is now a new html formating, but anyway thanks for the tip. The site is https://www.studentska-prehrana.si/sl/restaurant/Details/2521# and the Xpath is:
id('menu-list')/x:div[2]/x:div/x:div/x:div[2]/x:i/x:img
The code for the text  fetch I'll write myself.